# How to open this link in new tab inside bootgrid

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-bootgrid

I have embedded a download link for file based on file ID(FID) using a button.But my problem is that when the user presses download button page redirects to downloadfile.php. Instead when the user press download button the page should open in new tab.How can i achieve this?

```
"download": function(column, row) 
            {
                return '<a href="downloadfile.php?fid='+row["fid"]+'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info " data-row-id="' + row.fid + '">Download</buttn></a> ';
            },
```

I think i can fix this by adding target='_blank' attribute but when i modify the code as

```
"download": function(column, row) 
            {
                return '<a target='_blank' href="downloadfile.php?fid='+row["fid"]+'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info " data-row-id="' + row.fid + '">Download</buttn></a> ';
            },
```

The grid doesnt load.That is because of error.So how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in this line:-

```
return '<a target='_blank' href="downloadfile.php?fid='+row["fid"]+'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info " data-row-id="' + row.fid + '">Download</buttn></a> ';
```

You are mixing your use of single and double quotes. It should be:-

```
return '<a target="_blank" href="downloadfile.php?fid='+row["fid"]+'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info " data-row-id="' + row.fid + '">Download</button></a> ';
```

Your closing `' tag also contains a typo.

Comment: That's great @ElectronicsForKTU. Can you please accept this as the correct answer then to help others who look at the question.

Comment: I am a newbie here and dont have 15 reputation.Can you tell me how to accept this as correct answer?Cant seem to find how to do it..